# Can't find atlas_msgs pack after 2.3 update

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

After updating drcsim to version 2.3 it won't compile anymore my ROS application as it cannot find the package atlas_msgs anymore. How should i proceed?

Best regards,

LR

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2295/can%27t-find-atlas_msgs-pack-after-2.3-update./) by [Luis Filipe Rossi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/55/luis-filipe-rossi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 43 on 2013-04-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) on 2013-04-10**:
I'm seeing this trying to write a python module; I have nightly build and can't find atlas_msgs or osrf_msgs

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-04-10**:
I have verified this with the 2.3 deb and a source build. The command `rosmsg package osrf_msgs` shows `osrf_msgs/JointCommands`, but it won't import into python. EDIT: see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

one alternative is to do one of below:

```
>> import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('atlas_msgs')
```

or

```
>> import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('any_ros_package_that_depends_on_atlas_msgs')
```

before

```
>> import atlas_msgs
```

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Luis Filipe Rossi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/55/luis-filipe-rossi/) on 2013-04-10**:
Well, I am using C++ and no python. Any help on that?